# Error when creating ACL in Cloud Code: invalid permission type

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

**TL;DR**

Setting an ACL with a role permission fails *sometimes* because the role's name is interpreted as the permission type.

---

### The setup

In a Cloud Code function, I create an ACL object and use `setRoleReadAccess` to grant read access to a role:

```
const roleName = 'foo'; // this string is actualy calculated, but always non-nil and non-empty
const acl = new Parse.ACL();
acl.setRoleReadAccess(roleName, true);
```

Then I set that ACL to a new (unsaved) object:

```
const myObject = new MyObject()
myObject.setACL(acl);
```

### The error

The `setACL` call causes an exception with the error message `Tried to create an ACL with an invalid permission type.` which seems strange since I didn't provide a custom permission type.

### What I tried so far

- I tried to set the role as a `Role` object instead of a string, but that didn't make a difference.
- After some debugging I found that the error originates in ParseACL.js (line 85), where the `permission` string must either match `read` or `write`; however, in my case that string matches the role name (in the example above `"foo"`).

I have similar ACL/role code in other parts of my app, so I'm sure this *should* work. Now I'm looking for hints -- what might cause the weird behavior that the role name is interpreted as permission type -- and tips on how to further debug this issue.

(Using parse-server version 2.3.3 and node.js 6.4.0; I'm currently locked to that Parse version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by having `global.Parse = require('parse/node')` in a global Mocha test setup file; when running all integration tests (> 300 tests, taking about 4 minutes) this caused some weird effects like the mentioned `Tried to create an ACL with an invalid permission type`, but also `You cannot use [object Object] as a query parameter`; both errors only occurred when the runtime was under heavy load and running all tests -- just running a single test never produced any errors.

Details in this [Github issue](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3272).